# How to use an internal library Enum for Clap Args

Tags: rust, clap

I am currently working on a [Rust port](https://github.com/JuxhinDB/twistrs) of a security [tool](https://github.com/elceef/dnstwist). Inline with Rust's guides, I want to segregate the core library into its own crate, so that we can create various tools (CLI, API, streams etc.) that interface with with the core library without coupling them together.

The core library exposes two public Enums, one of them being the `PermutationMode` (truncated):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum PermutationMode {
    All,
    Addition,
    BitSquatting,
    Homoglyph,
}
```

When creating a CLI utility using [Clap](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap), I would like to extend this library Enum as part of the CLI like so:

```rust
use clap::Clap;

use twistrs::permutate::PermutationMode;

#[derive(Clap, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[clap(name = "twistrs-cli")]
struct Opts {
    #[clap(short, long)]
    registered_domains: bool,

    #[clap(arg_enum)]
    permutation_mode: PermutationMode,
}
```

So that when calling the CLI, we can pass the permutation mode from the user, to the CLI, to the library seamlessly and without having the CLI needing to be aware of the internal modes (in the event that the library adds more).

```
./twist-cli --registered-domains --permutation_mode=all example.com
```

---

Currently this does not seem to be possible (which makes sense). One attempt was to use type aliasing:

```rust
#[derive(Clap)]
type ArgPermutationMode = PermutationMode
```

However we cannot use derive macros for type-aliases. I tried also "cloning" the enum and trying to map to the libraries enum:

```rust
enum ArgPermutationMode {
    PermutationMode::All,
}
```

Which does not compile.

---

**Question** - Is it possible to extend an internal library Enum to use it as a Clap argument?

Comment: Note that if you implement `FromStr` for `PermutationMode` then you can just use it directly, or you could use a stand-alone parser with e.g. `#[clap(parse(try_from_str = my_permutation_mode_parser))]`

Comment: @JayDepp - That's how I ended up doing it. Turned out to be quite clean that way :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You would have to redefine the enum so that the `arg_enum!` macro can access the tokens.

If you add a conversion function between the two then you can make sure that upstream changes to the library enum force you to update your CLI, by giving you a compilation error:

```
arg_enum! {
    enum ArgPermutationMode {
        All,
        Addition,
        BitSquatting,
        Homoglyph,
    }
}

impl From<ArgPermutationMode> for PermutationMode {
    fn from(other: ArgPermutationMode) -> PermutationMode {
         match other {
             ArgPermutationMode::All => PermutationMode::All,
             ArgPermutationMode::Addition => PermutationMode::Addition,
             ArgPermutationMode::BitSquatting => PermutationMode::BitSquatting,
             ArgPermutationMode::Homoglyph => PermutationMode::Homoglyph,
         }
    }
}

impl From<PermutationMode> for ArgPermutationMode {
    fn from(other: PermutationMode) -> ArgPermutationMode {
         match other {
             PermutationMode::All => ArgPermutationMode::All,
             PermutationMode::Addition => ArgPermutationMode::Addition,
             PermutationMode::BitSquatting => ArgPermutationMode::BitSquatting,
             xPermutationMode::Homoglyph => ArgPermutationMode::Homoglyph,
         }
    }
}
```

You can reduce that boilerplate with a macro if you find yourself doing it a lot.

---

Given that you have control over the other crate, you could compromise by trying one of a few other options for a workaround:

- Define the actual enum variants in a separate file, and use `include!` to use the same source in both crates. This assumes your crates are in the same workspace.
- Use a macro derive like [`EnumIter`](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.18.0/strum_macros/derive.EnumIter.html) from [`strum_macros`](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.18.0/strum_macros/index.html). This will let you iterate over the enum's variants so you can supply them to Clap, without having a Clap dependency in that crate. You'll have a `strum_macros` dependency instead, so it's up to you if that is really better.
- Add the `clap_args!` call in the internal crate, but feature-gate it. Your application crate can enable this feature, but most users wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it was more on trying to see it from the perspective of a library implementer to ease the whole process. The feature-gate idea seems most appealing right now, as I see that happening with other examples as well.

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to @HamzaZubair; as of 10/01/24 it appears that using clap's [`ValueEnum`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/trait.ValueEnum.html) is a more suitable method of achieving this behaviour.

---

This is more of an extension to the above answer, incase it may help someone else. Ultimately what I ended up opting for was implementing [implementing `FromStr`](https://github.com/JuxhinDB/twistrs/blob/master/twistrs/src/permutate.rs#L37-L60) in the library as follows:

```rust
impl FromStr for PermutationMode {
    type Err = Error;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match s.to_ascii_lowercase().as_str() {
            "all" => Ok(PermutationMode::All),
            "addition" => Ok(PermutationMode::Addition),
            "bitsquatting" => Ok(PermutationMode::BitSquatting),
            "homoglyph" => Ok(PermutationMode::Homoglyph),
            _ => Err(),
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid having the client having to worry about the modes, we simply try to [parse the string](https://github.com/JuxhinDB/twistrs/blob/master/examples/twistr-cli/src/main.rs#L38-L42) passed through the CLI into one of the permutation modes.

```rust
let permutation_mode = matches
    .value_of("permutation_mode")
    .unwrap()
    .parse::<PermutationMode>()
    .unwrap();
```

This way we don't need to couple the modes between the client and the library and overall makes the example CLI a lot more malleable.

Comment: hi, "someone else" checking in; thanks for the code example, it's super helpful!

Comment: This is brilliant! But isn't it standard now to do it using clap's ValueEnum: https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/trait.ValueEnum.html

Comment: Thanks @HamzaZubair, wasn't aware of this. I've gone ahead and edited the answer to include this at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can Derive the FromStr trait using [Strum's](https://crates.io/crates/strum) [EnumString](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.EnumString.html) derive macro automatically.