# Enum to &str / &str to Enum

Tags: rust, enums

Wondering if there's a "proper" way of converting an `Enum` to a `&str` and back.

The problem I'm trying to solve:

In the `clap` crate, args/subcommands are defined and identified by `&str`s. (Which I'm assuming don't fully take advantage of the type checker.) I'd like to pass a `Command` `Enum` to my application instead of a `&str` which would be verified by the type-checker and also save me from typing (typo-ing?) strings all over the place.

This is what I came up with from searching StackOverflow and `std`:

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
pub enum Command {
    EatCake,
    MakeCake,
}

impl FromStr for Command {
    type Err = ();

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> std::result::Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match s.to_ascii_lowercase().as_str() {
            "eat-cake" => Ok(Self::EatCake),
            "make-cake" => Ok(Self::MakeCake),
            _ => Err(()),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> From<Command> for &'a str {
    fn from(c: Command) -> Self {
        match c {
            Command::EatCake => "eat-cake",
            Command::MakeCake => "make-cake",
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let command_from_str: Command = "eat-cake".to_owned().parse().unwrap();
    let str_from_command: &str = command_from_str.into();

    assert_eq!(command_from_str, Command::EatCake);
    assert_eq!(str_from_command, "eat-cake");
}
```

And here's a working playground:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b5e9ac450fd6a79b855306e96d4707fa

Here's an abridged version of what I'm running in `clap`.

```rust
let matches = App::new("cake")
    .setting(AppSettings::SubcommandRequiredElseHelp)
    // ...
    .subcommand(
        SubCommand::with_name(Command::MakeCake.into())
            // ...
    )
    .subcommand(
        SubCommand::with_name(Command::EatCake.into())
            // ...
    )
    .get_matches();
```

It seems to work, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something / a bigger picture.

Related:

- [How to use an internal library Enum for Clap Args](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62491508/16968574)
- [How do I return an error within match statement while implementing from_str in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67815130/16968574)

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, the [structopt](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.23/structopt/) crate handles exactly this sort of case. But it's a good question anyway! And no, I don't think you're missing anything.

Comment: Yea! I looks super cool, I also I remember stumbling upon `clap`s [beta documentation](https://docs.rs/clap/3.0.0-beta.4/clap/index.html#using-derive-macros) that seems to be using a similar syntax... But yea, just curious how others might deal with this outside this specific case. @Nathaniel Ford

Comment: The [`serializable_enum`](https://crates.io/crates/serializable_enum) or [`enum_from_str`](https://crates.io/crates/enum_from_str) crates could help here.

Comment: In fact, there are [a lot of crates](https://crates.io/search?page=1&per_page=10&q=enum%20str) that can do it.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks! Yea, I'm still not versed enough in rust to know when to grab a crate or when to just implement it myself with just `std`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [strum crate](https://github.com/Peternator7/strum) may save you some work. Using `strum` I was able to get the simple `main()` you have to work without any additional `From` implementations.

```rust
use strum_macros::{Display, EnumString, IntoStaticStr};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
#[derive(Display, EnumString, IntoStaticStr)]  // strum macros.
pub enum Command {
    #[strum(serialize = "eat-cake")]
    EatCake,
    
    #[strum(serialize = "make-cake")]
    MakeCake,
}
fn main() {
    let command_from_str: Command = "eat-cake".to_owned().parse().unwrap();
    let str_from_command: &str    = command_from_str.into();

    assert_eq!(command_from_str, Command::EatCake);
    assert_eq!(str_from_command, "eat-cake");
}
```

Comment: This looks like a really clean solution to the problem. I'm assuming from the number of crates available and the responses to this question that using my implementation and using a crate would be relatively similar and would just be up to the user to choose.

Comment: You are correct @se432